# Aggregate numeric column values for duplicate rowID and retain first occurrence value for non numeric columns

Tags: r

```
ID  Method  Sales
1   Call    10
2   Visit   20
3   Call    10
2   Visit   5
5   Call    5
1   Call    10
2   Visit   15
```

I would like the output to be:

```
ID  Method  Sales
1   Call    20
2   Visit   40
3   Call    10
5   Call    5
```

I am able to aggregate the sales based on ID but not sure how to bring in the Method.

Comment: look at `dplyr` `group_by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general solution (per your title) to

1. sum all numeric variables and
2. retain the first value of any non-numeric variables:

.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, sum) %>% slice(1)
```

Gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
     ID Method Sales
  <int>  <chr> <int>
1     1   Call    20
2     2  Visit    40
3     3   Call    10
4     5   Call     5
```

Comment: Worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By using package `dplyr` `group_by` and `summarise`:

```
DF%>%group_by(ID)%>%dplyr::summarise(Method=first(Method),Sales=sum(Sales))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID Method Sales
  <int>  <chr> <int>
1     1   Call    20
2     2  Visit    40
3     3   Call    10
4     5   Call     5
```

EDIT base on your additional requirement : By using @lmo's dput

```
dat1=dat[ ,sapply(dat, is.numeric)]
dat2=data.frame(dat[ ,sapply(dat, is.numeric)==FALSE],dat$ID)
dat1=dat1%>%group_by(ID)%>%dplyr::summarise_all(sum)
dat2=dat2%>%group_by(dat.ID)%>%dplyr::summarise_all(first)
result=cbind(dat1,dat2)
result$dat.ID=NULL
```

Comment: Since OP wants to "retain first occurrence" you might want to use `first` instead `unique`.

Comment: Can this be modified to have several character columns (pick the first occurrence) and several numeric columns to be summed on ID. Thanks.

Comment: @Srini167 If that is the case , I prefer Axeman's answer , or you can split the dataframe to two by the variable type , numeric and character , then after groupby merge it together. I will update my post

Answer (score 0):

A solution in base R is to separately calculate the desired values and merge the results together:

```
merge(aggregate(Method~ID, dat, head, 1), aggregate(Sales~ID, dat, sum), by="ID")
  ID Method Sales
1  1   Call    20
2  2  Visit    40
3  3   Call    10
4  5   Call     5
```

---

For `data.table`, a solution would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .(Method=first(Method), Sales=sum(Sales)), by=ID]
   ID Method Sales
1:  1   Call    20
2:  2  Visit    40
3:  3   Call    10
4:  5   Call     5
```

**data**

```
dat <- 
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L), Method = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Call", "Visit"), class = "factor"), 
    Sales = c(10L, 20L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 15L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Method", "Sales"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```

Comment: How do i modify the code if I have several numeric columns to be aggregated?

Comment: It depends, for base R's aggregate, it's easiest if the same function is used. That's why I split into two calls to the function and merged. If same function (say `sum)`, then can do `aggregate(cbind(Sales=Sales, Units=Units)~ID, dat, sum), by="ID")` for example. The `data.table` extension should be self explanatory, just add the new columns inside `.()` in a similar pattern to those already there.